# Why doesn't my website stop loading (Svelte)

Tags: loading, svelte

I made a [portfolio website](https://kotayatagai.cf), but this site doesn't stop loading.
Sorce code is [here](https://github.com/kota-yata/Kota-Yatagai-Portfolio).

Does anyone have a solution? or the reason why this happens?

Comment: Is the source code reduced to the minimal possible example still showing the error? Did you try contacting your webspace provider?

Comment: Check out this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/ge64hr/removing_livereload_from_production/), you're serving livereload client side. Here's the solution from that post: "Edit: It turns up that gh-pages deploys whatever’s in the repo so the production build i made just before deploying would not be commited to the repo. It works correctly if you build for production beforehand, then commit and push, then deploy"

Answer (score 0):

Deploy only your bundled static files. I can access your entire svelte project under your domain. check the sources tab in your browser's DevTools.

since you use vercel for deployment, check this out.
https://github.com/vercel/serve

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for service workers (If you are using them)
   But more probably

**2) ALWAYS npm run build before firebase deploy**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).